# Why is my connection super slow on MongoDB Atlas vs local

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

When using MondgoDB Atlas with Node, I find that the connection and queries are running extremely slow (Taking several seconds). I've tried shared, serverless and dedicated setups with the same result. When I use my local MongoDB setup however, everything runs super smooth and my queries are fast as expected (my query is a simple insert).

Is this common? Is there a reason that the hosted connection runs super slow whereas my local runs fast? I'm not behind any firewall.

Answer (score 1):

The **region** where your MongoDB Atlas is located will also affect the connection quality.

Choose a closer **region**.

Comment: I should mention, I'm in the same region myself as is the Atlas deployment, so I'm as close as possible to the region.

Answer (score 1):

Mongodb local is in your pc and so it will be ofcourse faster than Atlas, and Atlas is in a server which may take more time to read/ write than local setup.
Mongodb Atlas do read /write in milliseconds, but it may vary depending on your query.

Where you calling Mongodb requests from ?Mongodbcli or a server or a client side application?

If it's taking more than 1 second you should check your internet speed, query optimization